# Change contents of a cell in a datagridview based on a condition

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am populating a datgridview from a SQL statement. The list is from a SharePoint calendar and I want to make the end date column be blank if the event is an all day event. Here is my code:

```
Me.UserDataTableAdapter.Fill(Me.WSS_ContentDataSet.UserData)

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("bit1").Value = True Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Datetime2").Value = ""
        End If
    Next
```

If I change the line which is supposed to remove the value of the datetime2 cell to a msgbox("This is an all day event") it works so the condition testing is fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't calling the correct cell name. It should have been:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Datetime2DataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value = ""
```